# Нахождение решений однородной СЛАУ

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Всем привет! Пишу программу, решающую химические уравнения (на уровне школьной программы), и столкнулся с проблемой на задаче, которая сразу казалась значительно легче: расстановка коэффициентов. Как я понимаю, что бы их найти надо найти решения однородной СЛАУ, где неизвестные - коэффициенты, а в уравнениях коэффициенты - количества химического элемента в каждом веществе. Или я что то не так понимаю, или методом Гаусса можно найти только тривиальное решение системы: все неизвестные равны 0. Следовательно надо решать ее методом подстановки и выражать через какую то одну переменную все остальные? Но я без понятия как это сделать. Буду очень благодарен, если мне кто то подскажет как это реализовать

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте математическую постановку задачи. Из того, что Вы написали, для человека далекого от химии, можно лишь понять, что у Вас есть СЛАУ, и почему-то универсальный метод Гаусса Вам не подходит.

Comment: Есть однородная СЛАУ, примерно такого вида: 8u = y
8u = 2x
2v = x + 2y Надо привести ее вот к такому виду: 
y = 4u
x = 2u
v = 5u
Т.е. все неизвестные выразить через какую то одну

Comment: Я понял, сейчас уже вечер - это время для отдыха, если будет окно утром, я напишу Вам решение.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду ждать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача сводится к решению матричного уравнения

```
Ax=By
```

где A -  квадратная матрица N x N, B - прямоугольная матрица N x M, соответственно вектор зависимых переменных x имеет размерность N, вектор независимых переменных y имеет размерность M, где 1 <= M < N. Тогда зависимость переменных X от Y в случае невырожденной матрицы A будет иметь вид

```
x=(1/A)By
```

где (1/A) обратная матрица к A. Следовательно Ваша задача расчета коэффициентов для искомой аналитической зависимости сводится к вычислению обратной матрица (1/A), что делается методом гаусса и последующим ее умножением на матрицу В.

Теперь очень не простая задача, объяснить все это умному школьнику, но который пока не знает, что такое матрица.

Пусть у вас есть N линейных уравнений c неизвестными x1, x2, ..., xN и свободно изменяемыми параметрами y1,y2, ...yM, которые можно записать в виде:

```
 a11*x1+a12*x2+...a1N*xN=b11*y1+b12*y2+...b1M*yM
 a21*x1+a22*x2+...a2N*xN=b21*y1+b22*y2+...b2M*yM
 .........................
 aN1*x1+aN2*x2+...aNN*xN=bN1*y1+bN2*y2+...bNM*yM
```

Теперь предположим, что y1=1, все остальные y2 = y3 = yM = 0, то есть имеем систему уравнений с постоянными коэффициентами

```
 a11*x1+a12*x2+...a1N*xN=b11
 a21*x1+a22*x2+...a2N*xN=b21
 .........................
 aN1*x1+aN2*x2+...aNN*xN=bN1
```

Решим ее методом Гаусса (Мы полагаем, уравнения независимы) и запишем решение  виде:

```
 x1=d11
 x2=d21
 .........................
 xN=dN1
```

Это решение было получено для y1=1, соответственно для произвольного y1, его для линейного уравнения можно записать в виде:

```
 x1=d11*y1
 x2=d21*y1
 .........................
 xN=dN1*y1
```

Теперь пусть y2=1, все остальные y1 = y3 = yM = 0, и получим уравнение

```
 a11*x1+a12*x2+...a1N*xN=b12
 a21*x1+a22*x2+...a2N*xN=b22
 .........................
 aN1*x1+aN2*x2+...aNN*xN=bN2
```

решая которое методом Гаусса получим коэффициенты d12,...,dN2. Соответственно решение для произвольных y1 и y2 может быть записано в виде суммы решений:

```
 x1=d11*y1+d12*y2
 x2=d21*y1+d22*y2
 .........................
 xN=dN1*y1+dN2*y2
```

Повторяя этот процесс, мы в конечном итоге получим решение, которое Вам нужно:

```
 x1=d11*y1+d12*y2+...+d1M*yM
 x2=d21*y1+d22*y2+...+d2M*yM
 .........................
 xN=dN1*y1+dN2*y2+...+dNM*yM
```

Здесь нужно сразу сказать, что предложенная схема не эффективна, так как требует, чтобы линейное уравнение решалось M раз. Правильный способ я описал выше (через обращение матрицы и умножения на матрицу B), но для этого Вам надо прочесть любой учебник по линейной алгебре за первый семестр. Для умного школьника, который программирует и собирается учиться дальше, это очень простая задача. Вот для начала ссылка https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86 . Ну и думаю, что не нужно говорить, что не следует писать свою версию программы решения линейных уравнений и обращения матриц (это можно делать только в учебных целях), а нужно найти уже готовые и оттестированные решения.

Comment: Извините, а можно несколько подробнее и более простыми словами? Просто я школьник и пока не особо в этом разбираюсь

Comment: Можно, но либо поздно вечером или завтра утром :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Свободно изменяемые параметры - это, я так понимаю те переменные, через которые мы выражаем остальные? Тогда такой вопрос: как определить какие из переменных зависимые, а какие независимые?

Comment: Те, которые мы можем менять и которые стоят в правой части y1, y2,..,yM - это свободные или независимые переменные. Соответственно x1, x2,...xN - зависимые. Конкретно, что выбрать в качестве независимых переменных Вы решаете сами из физической интерпретации задачи. P.S.: если Вы получили от меня полезную информацию, то пожалуйста отметьте мой ответ зеленой галочкой, в противном случае вряд ли кто-то будет тратить время на написание пространных ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Первые ссыдки в гугле:
Реализация на [C#](https://www.scienceforum.ru/2016/1941/24158)
Реализация на [C++](https://prog-cpp.ru/gauss/)

Надеюсь, поможет)

Comment: Я же писал в вопросе по поводу метода Гаусса: он мне не подходит